# Firefox Extension File Structure

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I'm working on updating a Greasemonkey compiler to package Firefox extensions. I think the original version was for Firefox version 3.6 and Greasemonkey version 0.7.20070607.0, and the source code is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/arantius/greasemonkey-compiler). I'm going to be working on my update [here](https://github.com/SKladky/greasemonkey-compiler).

I'm trying to figure out what the current requirements are for Firefox 9/10 extensions so that I can make sure that I am generating the appropriate file structure.

Does anyone know if the following file structure is the current one:

```
MyExt/
    chrome/
        chrome/chromeFiles/
            chrome/chromeFiles/content/
                MyExt.js
    defaults/
        defaults/preferences/
            prefs.js
    chrome.manifest
    install.rdf
```

The original compiler outputs this for a Greasemonkey script that does not modify the browser chrome:

```
MyExt/
    chrome/
    content/
        MyExt.js
        prefs.js
        compiler.js
        xmlhttprequester.js
    chrome.manifest
    install.rdf
```

The next step will be to make sure that the Greasemonkey code that the compiler uses is current, but I want to get my output goals clear first.

Answer (score 3):

That's a typical/acceptable structure (although most people wouldn't nest `content` under `chromeFiles`; `chrome/content` is sufficient). A typical structure [can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension#Setting_up_the_Development_Environment):

```
my_extension.xpi:             //Equal to a folder named my_extension/
  /install.rdf                //General information about your extension
  /chrome.manifest            //Registers you content with the Chrome engine
  /chrome/
  /chrome/content/  //Contents of your extension such as XUL and JavaScript files
  /chrome/icons/default/*     //Default Icons of the extension
  /chrome/locale/*            //Building an Extension# Localization
  /defaults/preferences/*.js  //Building an Extension# Defaults Files
  /plugins/*
  /components/*
  /components/cmdline.js
```

However, note the following:

- The files under `chrome` can actually be placed anywhere you want, as long as you register those locations properly in the `chrome.manifest`
- Components can also be located anywhere. As with the chrome files, the location must be registered in the manifest.
- Defaults, on the other hand, [must be in the `defaults` folder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension#Defaults_Files):

  > Defaults files that you use to seed a user's profile with should be
  >   placed in defaults/ under the root of your extension's folder
  >   hierarchy. Default preferences .js files should be stored in
  >   defaults/preferences/ - when you place them here they will be
  >   automatically loaded by Firefox's preferences system when it starts so
  >   that you can access them using the Preferences API.
- Both `install.rdf` and `chrome.manifest` should reside in the top-level directory of the extension

Comment: The rule for `components` is no longer true. As of Firefox 4 the components can be placed anywhere - the corresponding entries in `chrome.manifest` simply need to be adjusted then. See [XPCOM changes in Gecko 2.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0).

Comment: @WladimirPalant - Bah, typing without thinking. Updated. Thanks.